# Extract Words in Excel that starts With B and have length of 10 chracters

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g602i.png)I need to Extract word having first letter Capital B and word length is 10 digit from excel sheet data.

Example: if cell A1 contains " ASIN [ASIN is erroneously marked as ASIN: B07VYZC00H, the value is null but B010976527." So in this sentence or a paragraph

i need to extract "B07VYZC00H" and "B010976527".

Comment: The example you gave does not contain 10 digits. Please clarify.

Comment: I mean it can contains letters and digits. so any thing that starts with B followed by more 9 digits or letter

Comment: Example you can take this.  Cell A1 contains the sentence like There are 7658 Asin B01GHT1200 :st.  Now here i have to fetch the value B01GHT1200  from each cell

Comment: Please help me. I really need to fix this asap.

Answer (score 0):

Try following formula.

```
=IF(AND(CODE(LEFT(A1,1))=66,LEN(A1)=10),A1,"")
```

[image]

Comment: @NavneetSingh I have added screenshot. Show your sample data and expected output.

Comment: @NavneetSingh fetch means what?

Comment: =IF(AND(CODE(LEFT(A1,1))=66,LEN(A1)=10),A1,"") this will work only if we have anything with 10 characters. But if cell contains a sentence and in between there is a word B01GJHD123 then its not detecting.

Comment: Fetch means the same like it shoud take out all the words from sentences that starts with B and have 10 characters.

Comment: So, your question would be `Extract word having first letter Capital B and word length is 10 digit`?

Comment: I am so sorry for not putting up the exact requirements. Yes i mean extracting.

Comment: I will give an another example if cell A1 contains " ASIN [ASIN is erroneously marked as ASIN: B07VYZC1VH, the value is null but B010976527." So in this sentence or a paragraph i need to extract "B07VYZC1VH" and "B010976527".

Comment: Please help me sir to fix it. It will be really great.

Answer (score 0):

To extract word having first letter Capital B and word length is 10 digits

Try this Textjoin+Filterxml formula, of which Textjoin available since Office 365 or above

In `B1`, array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) copied down :

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","a/b[starts-with(.,'B') and string-length(.)=10]"))
```

[image]

Edit : result as in adding new data in cell `A3`

[image]

Comment: Its working for few cells but for few its not fetching all the words eg, cell value have data " Restricted Product Review Request edit
ASIN B07WN2YWGF is erroneously marked as restricted
Regarding listing:
ASIN: B07ZG9FHPS,
Marketplace: 1,
Merchant ID: 25505675915
Merchant SKU: WTV-1902"
 so in this it extracted B07WN2YWGF  but not the second B07ZG9FHPS

Comment: Is there a space between ASIN: and B07ZG9FHPS? If not, that would explain why it's not extracted.

Comment: Yes there is a space in that

Comment: It is worked for me, see my edited post 2nd screenshot table. (reminding it is an array formula, to be confirmed by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER 3 keystrokes together instead of just ENTER )

Comment: Hi, can i share you my excel sheet and you can do it for me. I guess its bot complicated in my sheet.

Comment: Yes i have entered by using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: post your formula information and show what do you use of it?

Comment: Hi I have posted the link for formula. You also can see in few output it shows as !value

Comment: The returning "#VALUE!"  is meaning that your source data doesn't find matching criteria data. Then the formula can wrap with an error trap something like : =IFERROR(formula ,"")

Comment: I got the point, actually there are additional spaces. I need to remove the additional spaces to make this work. How i can remove the additional spaces and keep cell data in a single sentence?

Comment: Adding a TRIM function to remove the additional spaces and remain one, something like ....TRIM(A1)...., but additional space doesn't affect the FILTERXML formula result. I guess your source data have other character like ";", ":", or "-" in follow the 10 characters criteria, then this is a problem.

Comment: Thanks alot brother. You are a life saver. Really appreciate it.